# Why can't I upload the image file from Mobile but PC?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have implemented the uploading image function to my app using gem called 'paperclip'.

It works fine when I upload the image file from PC, but it doesn't save the image if I upload from Android's default browser.
It shows flash message 'it saved!' but it didn't.

But if take this part it saves fine. this is so weird.

**models/comment.rb**

```
validates_attachment_content_type :comment_icon, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png','image/gif']
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the mobile browsers dont support uploading of images from their storage. Your code is working fine its a problem with browsers support.

Comment: but if I take that part off, it works. In addition, it works fine with Mobile Opera, or Mobile FireFox.  Just Android's default browser won't take it...

Comment: debug and check the file content type when it is sent from a default android broswer and mobile opera, that could help you.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. How can I put the debug when I'm uploading from android's default browser?

Comment: Not on the andorid part you can put a breakpoint in your ruby code and check what request have you got

Comment: Thanks but how? in controller? or view?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21706/discussion-between-abhay-kumar-and-mkk)